# What is the difference between uid and sAMAccountName

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

What is the difference between [uid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680508(v=vs.85).aspx) and [sAMAccountName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679635(v=vs.85).aspx) attributes of a Microsoft Active Directory.

Edit : I am aware of the fact that `sAMAccountName` is a mandatory field and `uid` is not. Can someone explain how they differ from each other in terms of usage

Comment: uid is often "<Not Set>" in AD.  In general you should use samaccountname.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That's uidNumber. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680511(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @smoore4 Thank You for your inputs. I am aware of the fact that sAMAccountName is mandatory and uid isn't. What I am looking for is, how they differ from each other in terms of usage

Comment: Not sure why someone would downvote this question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`uid`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms680508.aspx) is a multi-value attribute. It's also not enforced as unique, so it's not appropriate as a unique identifier, unless you check for uniqueness before you set it. But that's your responsibility to maintain.

It is also not indexed, so it will be a little slower to search for an account by `uid`.

And it cannot be used for logging in.

So basically, use it for whatever you want to use it for, but you're responsible for what you put there.

[`sAMAccountName`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679635(v=vs.85).aspx) on the other hand, is single-valued, enforced unique on the domain, indexed, and can be used for authentication.